# boost:asio::write writes to socket successfully, but server doesn't see the data

Tags: c++, docker, sockets, boost

I've written a simple code sample that writes some data to the socket towards a simple TCP echo server. The data is written successfully to the socket (`writtenBytes > 0`), but the server doesn't respond that it has received the data.
The application is run in a Docker devcontainer, and from the development container, I'm communicating with the `tcp-server-echo` container on the same network.

```
io_service ioservice;
tcp::socket tcp_socket{ioservice};

void TestTcpConnection() {
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver nameResolver{ioservice};
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query{"tcp-server-echo", "9000"};
  boost::system::error_code ec{};
  auto iterator = nameResolver.resolve(query, ec);
  if (ec == 0) {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end{};
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iterator;
    tcp_socket.connect(endpoint, ec);
    if (ec == 0) {
      std::string str{"Hello world test"};
      while (tcp_socket.is_open()) {
        auto writtenBytes =
            boost::asio::write(tcp_socket, boost::asio::buffer(str));
        if (writtenBytes > 0) {
          // this line is executed successfully every time.
          // writtenBytes == 13, which equals to str.length()
          std::cout << "Bytes written successfully!\n";
        }
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `writtenBytes > 0` is a sign of a successful write to the socket.

The echo server is based on `istio/tcp-echo-server:1.2` image. I can ping it from my devcontainer by name or IP address with no issues. Also, when I write a similar code sample but using async functions (`async_resolve`, `async_connect`, except for the `write` operation, which is not async), and a separate thread to run `ioservice`, the server does see my data and responds appropriately.

Why the server doesn't see my data in case of no-async writes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: All `writtenBytes > 0` means is at least one byte was written. The other side should see that at-least-one-byte, but you need to be a bit more careful in the general case to ensure the entire message was written.

Comment: How do you know that it didn't receive the data?  Also, where is the tcp_socket declared?  Could it be getting destroyed.  In general, the write function will return once the data has been provided to the OS level, but there are buffers.  If tcp socket is closed at that point, it's possible that it just dumps the data in the buffer, without sending it first.

Comment: @user4581301, in this case `writtenBytes == 13`, which is exactly the length of the str.

Comment: @DaveS 1) >> _How do you know that it didn't receive the data_ - When I test other adjusted boost.asio examples, the server reflects the received data in the Docker logs...
2)  _Also, where is the tcp_socket declared?_ - I've added the scope of `tcp_socket` in the question. It is declared in the .cpp file where the function is. 
3) I've also added the loop where I check if the socket is open before writing to it. It is open as the `write` is being executed every time...

Comment: Thanks, guys, I've found the issue. Added it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was with the Docker container that received the message. The image `istio/tcp-echo-server:1.2` doesn't write to logs unless you send the data with `\n` in the end.